# Python/Django: If 5 and 5.00 are different values (when expressed in Decimal), then

Tags: python, django, decimal

If 5 and 5.00 and 5.000 are all different, then why does Django's decimal field save without the .00 even when I have decimal_places=2

?

More importantly, how can I save a value 5.00 as 5.00 in Django without using String.

Comment: Which database engine?  SQLite is a special case.  All SQLite values are strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be more correct to say those are different *representations* of the same value '5'.

Internally, the value saved (unless you're actually storing a string) is 5.

When the value is displayed, ie converted to a string representation for the screen, it might be shown as 5, 5.00 or 5.000 but internally, it's still 5

The two decimal places do not appear (if I can put it that way) until the value is output.

You *can't* save a number with 2 decimal places *unless* you use a string.

Comment: You could also save "100 × value" as an int

Answer (score 2):

You have an argument that Django ought to enforce a certain precision on its Python objects, but `decimal_places` is probably more about maximum precision. I believe precision is not stored in the database, so it will be lost in any case.

In any case, if you want to enforce precision, use something like: `Decimal(5).quantize(Decimal(10)**-DECIMAL_PLACES)`

You can overload the `to_python` method in a custom `django.db.models.DecimalField` to ensure that a python Decimal object with the correct precision is returned.